# SDL Tridion Community Webinar (will be recorded)

Tags: discussion

A bit late notice, but as an FYI for the community, Julian Wraith hosts a regular SDL Tridion Community Webinar.

http://webinars.julianwraith.com/

September's REL topic by Mihai Cadariu is in progress, feel free to join if you happen to catch this. Otherwise the recording will be posted shortly. Check out [past Webinars](http://webinars.julianwraith.com/category/archive/) and/or contact Julian ([@julesdw on Twitter](https://twitter.com/julesdw)) if you're interested in presenting on a future topic.